# flutter canvas.drawPicture() are they batch optimized?

Tags: flutter, flutter-engine

Trying to build a brush engine in Flutter. Each strokes consists of multiple dabs to be drawn to canvas surface, for every stroke I record the drawCircle calls for dabs into `PictureRecorder`. And I draw them to canvas using  `Canvas.drawPicture()`.
I couldn't figure whether when `drawPicture` is called all the drawCircle calls will be batched together as one call to GPU / or per drawCircle a GPU call will be made.

went through Flutter engine source code, but couldn't be able to come to conclusion to myself. Any pointers would be really helpful?